# MediaPlayer.create() returns null for filepath

Tags: android

I am trying to creae mediaplayer from file path

```
private void play(String path) {
    MediaPlayer player = null;
    if (path.startsWith("assets/music")) {
        path = path.replace("assets/", "");
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        try {
            afd = mActivity.getAssets().openFd(path);
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                    afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }

    } else {

        player = MediaPlayer.create(mActivity, Uri.parse(path));
        

    }
    if (player != null) {
        player.setOnCompletionListener(releaseListener);
        player.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.e(TAG, "mp error: " + what + ", extra: " + extra);
                return true;
            }
        });
        player.start();
        mPlayer = player;
    }
}
```

from assets path it works but MediaPlayer.create(mActivity, Uri.parse(path)); always returns null

> full path is
>
> /storage/emulated/0/Download/Buzzer - 1.mp3
>
> assets path is
>
> assets/music/Buzzer - 1.mp3

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that the value of `path` that you are passing to `Uri.parse(path)` is `/storage/emulated/0/Download/Buzzer - 1.mp3`, that is not a valid `Uri`. Notably, there is no scheme. Either:

- Pass in a `File` that points to your desired file and use `Uri.fromFile()`, or
- Ensure that `path` has a scheme (e.g., `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Buzzer - 1.mp3`)

Comment: This issue happens on emulator.. Its not working on 5.1